# Trace messages in Adobe AIR app, debugged through iOS Simulator

Tags: flash, debugging, air, ios-simulator, trace

I'm developing an AIR app through Adobe Flash CC. It's supposed to run on iPads and other iOS devices.
I'm debugging it through native XCode device simulator, as described here: https://helpx.adobe.com/flash/using/packaging-applications-air-ios.html#id_86478

The app is running in the simulator flawlessly. The only problem is that I don't know where do the trace messages/error statements go. What do I need to do to access them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In iOS Simulator click shortkey cmd+/ or use menu Debug->Open System Log: http://take.ms/PyVRu . It will open Console: http://take.ms/am4DC